# How can I force a banner to size up and be full-width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width

I have been reading stack overflow for some time but this is my first post!

I have this website: https://oliv-collection.com/.

The banner on top is full width as long as the screen you view it with has a resolution of less than 1600px (the original picture width). Once the resolution is greater than that, the banner does not cover the entire width of the page.

Is there an easy way with CSS to make the width and height increase so as to cover the full width? I have been fighting with Google Inspector but can't figure out what to do!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to do this, but I managed something close to what you ask for by changing the styling of the banner images to the following:

```css
.slick-slider .nm-banner img, .nm-banner img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

What I did was replace `width: auto;` to `width: 100%` to make the image resize correctly, and remove `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`. With my change, the banner image will increase with the width of the screen even above 1600px. This works for me in Safari on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
width: 100%;
```

Whatever the width of the screen is, the banner will be with maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin of the HTML body in CSS to 0.

```
body {margin: 0;}
```